# A Linear ODE involving Differential Operators

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-operators

> The problem is 
>   $$x^{2n} \left (\frac{d}{dx} - \frac{1}{a}\right )^{n} y = ky$$

I'm pretty sure the first step is to take $x = e^{t}$ and play with the operators like so
$$\frac{d}{dt} = \frac{dx}{dt} \frac{d}{dx} = e^{t}\frac{d}{dx}$$

I'm not used to using operators in this fashion to solve ODEs so here is where i got lost but i think you can convert the operator part of the problem to

$$\left (\frac{e^{t}}{e^{t}}\frac{d}{dt}- \frac{a}{e^{t}}\right )^{n}$$
Can i just pull $e^{-nt}$ out of the operator? How does this work? any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When working with operators you have to be really careful with exchanging the order as the operator acts on anything that follows it. For example if we had $[x \frac{d}{dx}]y = xy'$ then you cannot change this to $[\frac{d}{dx} x]y = xy' + y$. If I understood you correctly you want to do something like writing $x^{2n}(\frac{d}{dx} - 1/a)^n$ as $(x^2 (\frac{d}{dx}-1/a))^n$ (or the other way around) which would not be correct.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! first theres a mistake in the problem, it should be $$\frac{d}{dx} - \frac{a}{x}$$I figured it would be something like that because everything inside the parenthesis is acting on $y$ so it makes sense you cant pull it out. Ive been working on it in paper and i'm expectinf this to telescope in some way but i cant quite figure it out. If im somehow able to turn the binomial $$\frac{d}{dx} -\frac{a}{x}$$ into a monomial this problem becomes alot simpler

Comment: For your updated problem I would take $y = x^a g$ and notice that $[D - a/x](x^a g) = x^a g'$ so that $[D - a/x]^2(x^a g) = x^a g''$ and so on. This will replace the $n$'th power of the operator acting on $y$ to $n$'th derivatives of $g$. (If, as I expect, there is no $x^{2n}$ in front in the updated problem this will then be solvable).